# Options for a 0-10V dimmer on a 3-way, in a basement

Tags: dimmer-switch, multiway-switch

I'm putting utility lights in a basement (3-way SW).  After running all the wire and switches I picked up the only lights that my electrical supply house carried, RAB LED utility lights.

Not cheap, but crazy bright, so I figured I could get by with less.  I get back to the house and realize that these have an extra set of wires for a 0-10V dimmer.

What are my options here? this is a basement.  I'm guessing I could just connect the two and get full brightness, but I would like to be able to tweak the brightness because they might be too bright.  What I don't want to do is pay $70 ea for 3-way dimmer's which is what home depot is charging.  Other than these overpriced switches, nothing says 0-10V.  Does anyone know if any low cost, off the shelf dimmers that happen to be 0-10.  I would probably mount it discretely above one of the lights to make adjustments.

Also, is there any reason an electrical inspector would have a problem with this?

Comment: Do you need *dimming* at both control locations, or just dimming at one and switching at the other?

Answer (score 3):

There are at least 4 different ways to dim mains AC powered lights (i.e., anything from 110V - 480V):

- Modification of the mains power fed to the lights

This is what typical residential applications use. It is cheap because of mass production (i.e., almost any home or office can use it) and easy because it generally involves "switch replacement" so that it can go "anywhere", even in circuits that were not originally set up for a dimmer.

However, it is not necessarily the most efficient way of doing things and **often incompatible with LED lighting**. Essentially, LED lights are so efficient and so different from incandescent lights, that they will suck up the power when they can and give you light (sometimes flashing) instead of dimming, unless the LED light and the dimmer are designed to be compatible with each other.

- Wireless remote control within each bulb or fixture

An example of these is [Philips Hue](https://amzn.to/3gMu12g):

[image]

They seem expensive, until you realize that each one essentially includes a microcomputer, WiFi receiver and lots of other good stuff. If you want to just "screw in new bulbs and dim from your phone or Alexa", this is the easiest solution. However, this doesn't give you "dim from your wall switch".

- Low-voltage lights with power line dimming

This is actually a very efficient way to do things. LEDs are low-voltage devices anyway, so converting from high voltage (mains) to low voltage (typically 12V - 24V) means that the LED lights don't have to do that conversion, which is more efficient and lower cost (though the cost savings isn't always so apparent as mass production of mains-powered LED lights lowers the cost there for different reasons).

- High-voltage lights with a *separate low-voltage signal for dimming*

This is what you have with the RAB lights. It is very efficient because you just use a tiny bit of power to control the dimming and don't need fancy electronics on the switches or in the power modules of the fixtures. There is electronics needed in the fixtures but, designed well, those can be much more efficient than dimming via the primary input power.

This type of signalling has a huge advantage in certain applications. In particular, it allows for remote control of different types of lights (incandescent, LED, etc.) and the dimmer does not have to be sized to handle the full power of the lights. Residential dimmer switches will often have a limit of 600W or similar, *less than even a standard 15A circuit* - i.e., you might have (in the old incandescent days at least) a large room with lots of lights on one circuit and find you can't even install an ordinary dimmer because the lights use too much power! With dimming through a separate low-voltage path, this problem goes away.

**Important:** This type of dimming uses *separate wires* from the actual power for the lights. Which means:

- You will need to run a separate set of wires for dimming
- If you are using conduit, those wires *might* have to be in a separate conduit (or outside conduit) as you *generally* can't mix high & low voltage wires. (Exception if all the low voltage stuff is rated to exist around high voltage. It gets complicated. Separate is easiest.)
- The good news: As noted by Harper, the dimmer does not have to be in the same place as the main switches. So, for example, if you have the main 3-way switches by the doors (as is normal, and to a certain degree required by code), you could have the dimmer at a workbench or other convenient location.

But the end result is **you got lights that are not typically used in residential applications**, which is why the dimmer switches are expensive.

Answer (score 1):

The dimmable LED’s that I have in my plant can not have the main voltage altered those 2 extra leads are for dimming , I use full power / ~ 10% for night lighting I wire all the extra 2 wire dimmer controls into a control relay that connects those 2 leads and my light level is dimmed , some use a potentiometer to vary the voltage at the 2  leads but the mains voltage stays constant.  Most of these lights operate from 90v to 277v .

Check out what is needed but I think you will find a simple control is all that is needed to vary the light intensity dead short drops to aprox 10% open full brightness and multiple fixtures can be wired in parallel as long as observing polarity all the purple on w side gray on the other if they are similar to what I use.
As I said we just short them together but did use a potentiometer (variable resistor) until we realized that 10% was the minimum light level so we did not need the pot.

Comment: Right, that’s what I was hoping to do.  I just wasn’t sure if an off the shelf $8 dimmer had the appropriate resistance for a 0-10V circuit.

Comment: The wall dimmer may not work I never tried they are scr controlled. A simple variable resistor or pot to vary the voltage on the leads from zero to 10v was all that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

*Note that you only use one dimming method.  Dimming methods **do not stack***.

So it sounds like the Home Depot (why shop there?) 3-way dimmers are expensive. It’s just as well; those are going to be *triac dimmers*.  Which use the “modify the AC power” technique discussed above by mana’. Triac dimmers simply turn the AC power on or off prematurely; that is the cheap way to make a dimmer fit inside a traditional light switch box.

The “0-10V” method is a completely different technology, again as mana’ discusses above.

Your best bet is to wire up the 3-way switch circuit in the normal way, ignoring dimming altogether, using $1.50 3-way switches.

Then, if you feel you want to enable 0-10V dimming, add a third 0-10V *dimmer only* which allows you to trim the brightness up and down to satisfaction.  This would be where convenient and not near the switches.

*Nowhere is it written that the dimming control must be at the switch control.  The only reason it’s historically like that is the implementation of cheap triac dimmers.*

Comment: Most dimmers are scr a triac is back to back SCR’s (simplified explanation)  in most cheap electronic dimmers that’s how they can advertise automatic power savings because 1/2 of the wave is never used. Triac’s use the full wave.